# getting variables for partition size from diskpart in batch file

Tags: windows-command-prompt, diskpart

Im trying to execute part of a batch file only if a specific partition is at least a certain size. I found an example of diskpart being used in a batch file here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477576/get-the-amount-of-partitions-on-a-disk-0-using-batch-file

But when I try to modify it to get what I need out of it It stops working entirely. I've scaled back to just this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO select disk 0 > temp.scr
ECHO list partition >> temp.scr
diskpart /s temp.scr | findstr /r "Partition.[0-9]" > temp.txt
pause
```

based on how I THOUGHT the original worked, shouldn't this be outputting the string found with a regex to temp.txt? temp.exe is empty no matter what I try.

For what it's worth, the end goal is to have a batch file loaded into a winPE image, which is then run automatically with startnet.cmd. This batch file would look at each partition on the disk, find the relevant one (so larger than ~200 gb in this case) and then format that partition, then run some more batch files which I already have made and working.

Comment: You need to run the bat file you create as an administrator; it appears that a user process calling an elevated task is unable to capture the output of the diskpart command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch file will grab all the partition records and parse them into a series of temporary environement variables within the `For` command

```
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
ECHO list disk
ECHO select disk 0
ECHO list partition
) > %~dp0temp.scr
For /F "usebackq tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7" %%P IN (`diskpart /s %~dp0temp.scr ^| findstr /r "Partition.[0-9]"`) DO (
    If /i "%%S" EQU "KB" (
        REM Skip drives sized in KiloBytes
    ) Else If /i "%%S" EQU "MB" (
        REM Skip drives sized in MegaBytes
    ) Else (
        REM GB/TB
        If /i "%%S" EQU "GB" Set /A intSize=%%R * 1
        If /i "%%S" EQU "TB" Set /A intSize=%%R * 1024
        If !intSize! GEQ 200 (
            Echo Partition %%P  Type %%Q    Size !intSize! GB   Offset %%T %%U
            Call :s_Work_Partition %%P
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
pause
Goto :EOF
:s_Work_Partition
REM First parameter is disk partition number
If "%~1" EQU "" Goto :EOF
::  %~1 contains the partition number from disk 0
::  it can be used to run any disk command within this command block.


Goto :EOF
```

Within the body of the `For` command you have complete freedom to use the token data from the `DiskPart` process.
You must run this batch file as an administrator or it will not be able to work properly.

Because the `DiskPart` command uses the KB/MB/GB/TB suffixes to the disk size, the suffix is checked against known values to eliminate disks that are too small, but also be able to handle disks that are between 1 and 199 TB which are converted to 1024 - 203776 GB for comparison.

Additional commands can be placed in the code black at the bottom to further automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in a batch file - e.g. getpart 4 2
to get details of disk 4 partition 2

```
@Echo Off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7" %%B in ('^(echo sel disk %1^&echo list part^)^|diskpart^|FIND /I "Partition %2"') do set L_PART=%%B & set L_TYPE=%%C & set /A L_SIZE=%%D & set L_UNITS=%%E

echo L_PART=%L_PART% L_TYPE=%L_TYPE% L_SIZE=%L_SIZE% L_UNITS=%L_UNITS%

ENDLOCAL
```